# How to copy and paste changed some lines in (command mode) in Vim

Tags: vim

I has such code:

```
def foo
  puts "foo"
end
```

and as result I need:

```
def foo
  puts "foo"
end

def bar
  puts "bar"
end
```

I would like to perform this in command mode (could you also refer some help?) but other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues using commands proposed in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy / paster use type : (with you cursor on `def foo` line)

```
y3yGP
```

It will copy the 3 lines at the end of the file. use `xG` where `x` is a line number to go at line `x`. (Use `set number` to see line number)

Then you can change foo in bar with command :

```
:x,ys/foo/bar/
```

With `x` the first line of the block, and `y` the last one :)

Hoping that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Staying in insert mode I do the following (cursor on `def foo`):

```
S-vjjjyPgv:s/foo/bar/g
```

Nice trick for me is using gv to retrive last selection.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the following Ex command (assuming that the cursor is
located on the `def` line).

```
:,/^end/t//|'[,']s/\<foo\>/bar/g|'[pu!_
```

To jump to the pairing `end` line, one can take advantage of the
`%` command extended by the matchit plugin.

```
:exe"norm V%y']o\ep"|'[,']s/\<foo\>/bar/g
```